# TypeError: otherStatus.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function

I'm building a javascript function in ReactJS that takes some values from an HTML form and passes down the values to another event. Inside this function i'm using a regex expression to remove some characters I don't need from the values I retrieve. For some reason I'm getting this error. Can anyone please explain what i'm doing wrong or what I'm missing here.
This is my code:

```html
addCardtoApp = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const card = {
            taskName: this.taskName.current.value, 
            taskDescription: this.taskDescription.current.value,
            taskPeriod: this.taskPeriod.current.value,
        };
        const cardStatus = {
            taskStatus: this.taskStatus.current.value,
        }
        let otherStatus = {
            otherStatus: this.taskStatus.current.innerText,
        }
        otherStatus = otherStatus.replace('↵', '');
        console.log(otherStatus);
        this.props.addCard(card, cardStatus);
        event.currentTarget.reset();
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`otherStatus` is an object not a string value try like this :

```
    otherStatus = otherStatus.otherStatus.replace('↵', '');
```